# jQuery Datatable - Displaying row number when Scroller is enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to displaying the row number (in first column) in datatable but, it is displaying only for first few records and not displaying for the rest of them.

I tried to follow this example: 
https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html

I have enabled scroller in my datatable.

```js
var data = [];
        for ( var i=0 ; i<5000 ; i++ ) {
            data.push( [
            '', 
            'First Name ' + i, 
            'Last Name '+ i, 
            'Postal - ' + i, 
            'ZIP - '+ i, 
            'USA' ] );
        }
         
        var t = $('#example').DataTable( {
            data:           data,
            deferRender:    true,
            scrollY:        200,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            scroller:       true,
            info:false
        } );
 
  t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
      t.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
          cell.innerHTML = i+1;
      } );
  } ).draw();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.4.3/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.4.3/css/scroller.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>ZIP / Post code</th>
                <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

NOTE: Row number aren't tied to the data and change based on filters.

Any suggestion / help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No 100% sure but if you did like this and the iterator stop in few records i think may is the scrollY give you row iterate to 200px and in your case you need to add this column into json and no iterate dynamitically. What happen if you set to 5000 px this value change?

Comment: @headmax has a good point. `scrollY` seems to be a factor... Using `scrollY:200` numbers up to `54` while using `scrollY:300` numbers up to `81`. Now why... I can't tell. --- The suggestion about pushing row numbers in the `data` array is what I would do if the use is to be a row "id". If it is to just number the filtered rows (so row number aren't tied to the data and change based on filters) that is something else. **Please clarify this point for your use-case.**

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, row number aren't tied to the data and change based on filters. Updated the question with the same.

Answer (score 2):

I found your strange issue.

You missed `paging:false` to disable pagination... Which was interfering with the row numbering objective you have.

I found it suggested in this [documentation about scrollY](https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollY).

And there was `scroller:true`, which needs pagination to work... And which is used in conjunction with an ajax ressource. Not your case in posted code.

I'll let you read the whole [documentation about scroller](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/).

---

Seems like the two options are friends. It's one or the other.

I made your row numbering to work in [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/MEGyQr?editors=1010).

Comment: Appreciate your response. In my case, I need scroller:true. I need virtual rendering of data so, scroller is set to true. Also, I cannot set paging to false as scroller depends on paging.

Comment: The choice of one or the other option depends on your data source. Ajax "scroller" needs pagination while data provided as a JavaScript array needs pagination false to number them all... That is how it works.